# how do i differ my abstract from my introduction?

Tags: introduction

My topic is a causal argument. I choose what causes criminal behavior and am going to touch on the points of environment, personality disorders, education, genetics, and family controversy.

Comment: well reasoning for the abstract is with it being a causal paper it has to be in  APA format and am required to have an abstract.

Comment: Two possible duplicates: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/difference-b-w-abstract-and-introduction-writing-for-a-research-paper  and http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10375/difference-between-an-abstract-and-an-introduction-in-a-feature-article